# how to access and sort 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a script to initalize 2d array in javascript by reading txt file. Here are some portions of my code

```
var neighbor = {};
var temp = new Array();
neighbor[nodemap[ temparray[0]]] = temp; //nodemap[ temparray[0]] is an integer
neighbor[nodemap[temparray[0]]]. push(nodemap[temparray[1]]);
neighbor[nodemap[temparray[0]]]. push(nodemap[temparray[2]]);
.... // continue to add value
```

Then I want to access and sort the array, like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < n_count; i++);
{
  for (var k = 0; k < neighbor[i].length; k++);
    neighbor[k].sort(function(a,b){return a - b})
}
```

However, I got the error that `neighbor[i] is unidentified`.  Could you please show me how to fix that?

Comment: Well ... what is `i`?

Comment: i guess u should have used 'k' instead of i ? is 'i' in scope ?

Comment: Sorry, it's k... I made mistakes, i editted the post already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `neighbor` "array" is actually an object literal. So the way you should loop over `neighbor` is:

```
for (var key in neighbor) {
    var cur = neighbor[key];
    cur.sort(function (a,b) {
        return a - b;
    });
}
```

Comment: If `neighbor[i]` is undefined then `neighbor[i][k]` won't be accessible either. I also think `neighbor[i]` is supposed to be an array that they want to sort.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yeah I'm starting to realize a few things. I've been editing to explain more. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @JoshVo I know, I've been editing my answer. I just finished. Does that help? Can you provide a jsFiddle with your actual filling of `neighbor`?

Comment: thanks Ian. It works. However, I still need to write back right? (i.e neighbor[key] = cur;) Is there any method I could sort directly? I am working with a very large data...

Comment: @JoshVo No, you don't need to write back. When you have `var cur = neighbor[key];`, `cur` will be a reference to the specific array in `neighbor`. So it gets modified in place. Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/DwaAa/ . And I can't think of any other way to sort these

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that I need to sort the key in neighbor also.(for example, neighbor[1], neighbor[2], neighbor[3]... ) How can I do that? (sorry for asking too many questions, but I just moved from c++ to javascript...)

Comment: can we [continue this discussion in chat, thanks](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27648/discussion-between-josh-vo-and-ian)